# can needs-data be an array in drupal hook_token_info?

Tags: 7

Can the function `hook_token_info()` have an array for needs-data ?

```
hook_token_info()  {
 $type = array(
                'name' => t('ABC Settings'),
                'description' => t('Tokens related to ABC admin settings.'),
                'needs-data' => array('abc_user','abc_trans' ,'abc_trans_sub' ,'abc_gist_email_for_report_download','abc_gist_email',
                                      'abc_st_email' ,'abc_send_fax'),
                );}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no type limit on needs-data. It all depends on how do you want to call [token_replace()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!token.inc/function/token_replace/7). On the other hand, it might be wise to use 'node' approach - when you provide node, you provide also user object of node's author, even if it is never provided or mentioned in `needs-data` explicitly.

Comment: thanks..but whenever i check the hook_tokens function, the type i get is always node . then how can i add custom tokens?